# Сonflict onBlur event with events on other elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input with an onBLur event and a button located in another part of the application
how to avoid conflict onBLur and clicking on this button, because by clicking on this button I also get a trigger
onBLur events

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: When you focus a button, your input will lose focus (and trigger the blur event) I'm afraid I don't understand what the problem is. Please try and give a detailed description of the problem, and if possible, the code to reproduce it.

Comment: when I lose focus, the onblur event is triggered and closes the element, but at the same time on the other element there is a click event that makes another action, and so despite the fact that I click on this element, onBLur still fires
maybe there is a way to subscribe to the document and track clicks, and if an event occurs on a certain element, cancel onBLur

Comment: Won’t the onBlur event on the first element fire before the click on the second element so there is no chance of cancelling it?